# How can I add color to just the wave texture of my tree?

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, shader-nodes

I have a model tree with snow on top, and I would like to be able to color the rest of the tree without affecting the snow. I am using the "Z" axis from the normals coordinate to add the snow effect and a wave length texture for the bark. What I am hoping to be able to do is affect the colors of these two textures separately but cannot come up with a way. Thank you in advance for the help.

[image: Current node setup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the "snow" *ColorRamp* as a factor to mix the snow and bark. The bark is the *Wave Texture* colorized by a *ColorRamp* node. The snow is just a white color in this example.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: thank you so much. I knew it'd be something simple.